# ERROR RollingFileAppender

Tags: apache2

When I check the service unifi status I see this error and would like to clear it up. I am noob+ in Ubuntu so I can figure things out if given clear instructions on where to start looking and how to look. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

```
ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.
RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.
IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.
RollingFileAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.
RollingFileAppender
```

Answer (score 2):

This is usually a write permissions issue, where the service is not permitted to write to the logging location.

In your `log4j.xml` file you'll see sections that look like this:

```
<RollingFile
    name="RollingFile"
    fileName="${log.dir}/le-${app}.log"
    filePattern="${log.dir}/le-${app}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz"
    ignoreExceptions="false"
    ...
</RollingFile>
```

Note the `{log.dir}` location and confirm that the service running Unifi is able to write to that directory. If it cannot, consider creating a specific directory for the service to use like this:

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/unifi
sudo chown -R {unifi}:{unifi} /var/log/unifi
```

<sup>**Note:** Be sure to change `{unifi}` to whatever username is running the service.</sup>

The location does not need to be within `/var/log` if you would rather the logs be written somewhere else.

Comment: **UPDATE**
I upgraded the service from 6.5.55 to 7.0.22 and the error was cleared up. I am saving these commands to look more into them as I stated I learn commands through example and this should help me in the future and hopefully help somebody else.

It is unifi. I will follow the commands shown as I am not good at Ubuntu so commands get the best of me unless I know what they are.